# How to open an android emulator and install an .apk at the same time from the same terminal?

Tags: android, command-line, apk, emulation

I have a bizarre problem: I want to start an android emulator and at the same time install an already built .apk. The thing is that I want to do all these from the command line and especially from ONE terminal. (actually from a Makefile...).

If i start the emulator, it never stops until I close it thus I cannot execute any other command. On the other hand I don't know emulator's name before hand, although probably will be 5554.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not start the emulator in the background?  From the command line, this is done by appending an ampersand to the command:

```
emulator -avd <whatever> &;
```

and then communicate with it via ADB:

```
adb install MyApp.apk
```